# Hiding content in html email for Office 365

Tags: email, responsive-design, outlook, html-email, office365

I have been unable to hide content in Office 365 that is for a mobile-only portion of an email. I have hid the content in other email clients, including Gmail and Outlook 2007 and 2013. Is there a workaround for Office 365?

Here's a sample of a template I've been working with:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">

    body {
    width:100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    img {
        outline:none;
        text-decoration:none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table td {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        mso-table-lspace:0pt;
        mso-table-rspace:0pt;
        padding:0;
    }
    .yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link, .yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span {
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        border-bottom:none !important;
        background:none !important;
    }
    .ReadMsgBody {
        width:100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
        width:100%;
    }

    /* END OF GLOBAL RESETS */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px), screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* START OF MOBILE GRID */ 

    *[class=hide] {
        display:none !important;
    }
    *[class].block {
        width:400px!important;
        display:block!important;
        clear:both!important;
    }
    *[class=showmobile] {
        display:block !important;
        margin:auto !important;
        width:400px!important;
        height:auto !important;
        max-height:inherit !important;
        overflow:visible !important;
    }
    }
    span.yshortcuts {
        color:#000;
        background-color:none;
        border:none;
    }
    span.yshortcuts:hover, span.yshortcuts:active, span.yshortcuts:focus {
        color:#000;
        background-color:none;
        border:none;
    }
    [class].contenteditable {
        -webkit-user-select: text !important;
        -khtml-user-select: auto !important;
        -moz-user-select: auto !important;
        -ms-user-select: auto !important;
        -o-user-select: auto !important;
        user-select: auto !important;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffffff" margin="0" style="-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; width:100% !important; background:#ffffff; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!--Wrapper-->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><!--content-->

          <table width="750" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="hide" align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="235" class="hide"><img src="http://www.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg" width="235" border="0" style="display:block;" alt=""/></td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  width="235" class="hide"><img src="http://www.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg" width="235" border="0" style="display:block;" alt=""/></td>
                <td width="235" class="hide"><img src="http://www.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg" alt="" width="235" border="0" style="display:block;"/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!--content end--> 

          <!--  mobile only content -->

          <div  height="0" style="display:none; width:0px; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden;" class="showmobile">
            <table height="0"  width="235" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="showmobile" style="margin:0 auto; display:none; border:0;">
              <tr>
                <td class="showmobile block" align="left"><table width="235" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="showmobile" style="margin:0 auto; display:none;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="http://www.wnyc.org/i/620/372/l/80/1/blackbox.jpeg" width="235" border="0" style="display:block;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" align="center"  style="padding: 8px; line-height: 12px;background-color:#ed008c;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff;"> To unsubscribe, click here</a>. </span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

          <!-- end mobile only content --></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--End Wrapper-->

</body>
```

Comment: Even though we all thought it impossible, Microsoft has made a new email application that is worse than its predecessor. Please read [this](http://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2014/07/22/office-365-quirks-for-email-designers/) and [this](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C4/the_pulse_office_365_first_impressions) and just accept that there's very little to be done.

Answer (score 0):

After spending the last couple days trying to come up with a solution for just this the best I could come up with was adding an inline style to the containing cell of "font-size: 0px;". In a media query I simply set the font-size back to desired.